# How to get number of rows, columns /dimensions of tensorflow.data.Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, data-science, tensorflow-datasets

Like pandas_df.shape is there any way for tensorflow.data.Dataset?
Thanks.

Comment: [output_shapes](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#output_shapes) method of Dataset class gives you the dimension of each data point. But since the Dataset api defines an iterator to access your data, I do not think there is any way to know the number of data points you have up front. There could be private variables that hold some property that would give more details though if we take a look at the source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with something built-in, but the shapes could be retrieved from `Dataset._tensors` attribute. Example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def dataset_shapes(dataset):
    try:
        return [x.get_shape().as_list() for x in dataset._tensors]
    except TypeError:
        return dataset._tensors.get_shape().as_list()
```

And usage:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

x_train, y_train = make_blobs(n_samples=10,
                              n_features=2,
                              centers=[[1, 1], [-1, -1]],
                              cluster_std=0.5)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train)
print(dataset_shapes(dataset)) # [10, 2]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
print(dataset_shapes(dataset)) # [[10, 2], [10]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to tf and learning/using tf 2 alpha. I was not able to reproduce this code in tf 2.0.

Comment: just ran it in tf-2-alpha. It does work. What error do you have? Please post it here

Comment: OK, the result slightly differ in TF2. For the exact result as I provided here use something like this: `def dataset_shapes(dataset): res = [x.get_shape().as_list() for x in dataset._tensors]; return res if len(res) > 1 else res[0]`

Comment: Yes, it does work for tf2. But your solution is not giving exactly the shape of dataset. I used a simpler dataset: `dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
   {"a":tf.random.uniform([4]),
    "b":tf.random.uniform([4, 3], maxval=100, dtype=tf.int32 )})`  and it returns [[4], [4, 3]] but it should return [4,2] as it has 4 rows and 2 columns. I used parts of your code to get the dimensions `rows=dataset2._tensors[0].get_shape()[0]` `cols=len(dataset2._tensors)`

Comment: This function does not work for tensorflow_datasets though. I applied it to mnist_train but did not work.                                                                   
  `dataset, info = tfds.load('mnist', data_dir='gs://tfds-data/datasets', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)` ...
`mnist_train, mnist_test = dataset['train'], dataset['test']`

Comment: (1) You haven't mentioned that you are using TF2 in your question. (2) You asked a question about `tensorflow.data.Dataset` and not about `tensorflow_datasets`. (3) I can't provide a solution for every possible iterable that you might put into dataset + It's trivially to extrapolate for other cases if you know how to extract shapes from tensors and have a small knowledge of Python.

Comment: This solution does not work for me in tf 2. It says that _tensor is not an attribute of `TakeDataset` or `ShuffleDataset`

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Vlad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55620373/3136741), just in case someone is trying this out for datasets downloaded via tfds, a possible way is to use the dataset information:

```py
info.features['image'].shape # shape of 1 feature in dataset
info.features['label'].num_classes # number of classes
info.splits['train'].num_examples # number of training examples
```

Eg. tf_flowers :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds 

dataset, info = tfds.load("tf_flowers", with_info=True) # download data with info

image_size = info.features['image'].shape # (None, None, 3)
num_classes = info.features['label'].num_classes # 5
data_size = info.splits['train'].num_examples # 3670
```

Eg. fashion_mnist :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds 

dataset, info = tfds.load("fashion_mnist", with_info=True) # download data with info

image_size = info.features['image'].shape # (28, 28, 1)
num_classes = info.features['label'].num_classes # 10
data_splits = {k:v.num_examples for k,v in info.splits.items()} # {'test': 10000, 'train': 60000}
```

Hope this helps.